# Save failed in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I opened a number of tabs at the same time. I think that's why Google Colab was not able to support the heavy load. The message stated:

> **Save failed**
>
> This file could not be saved. Please use the File menu to download the .ipynb and upload the notebook to make a copy that includes your recent changes.

Is downloading the file and uploading again the only solution?

Comment: Hi, I am wondering whether you found the reason for this issue keep happening. Can it be phishy activities on the computer or the cloud?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can happen if you open the same notebook in multiple tabs and make incompatible edits to the notebook. At this point, the only way to save your work is to follow the advice in the dialog. To prevent this in the future, avoid simultaneously editing the same notebook in multiple browser windows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I didn't open the same notebook repeatedly. The other tabs are different files.

Comment: This should not be showing as the answer when the OP has indicated that this is not the case.

Comment: I can confirm that it is possible to get the saving error while working in a single tab.
It's quite easily reproducible and seems to be caused by heavy outputs such as images.

Answer (score 17):

It turned out to be a network issue. Output is heavy and colab is not able to save it is not able to make a handshake because internet speed is poor. So just switch the internet source and see it working.

Comment: definitely helped thanks for solution. colab is wierd

Answer (score 3):

I deleted (heavy) outputs and it worked out, it started saving without fail notifications

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem **despite** ''Runtime > Change runtime type' being already set 'None' beforehand. As the OP I had **no** other instances of the notebook open.

In the end I did 3 things in the following order:

1. File > Save a copy in Drive
2. File > Save a copy in GitHub
3. File > Save

Just picking the 'Save' from the drop down again did the trick for me. My variables were still loaded all is working as before.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @Nazgul Mamasheva made me think about it.

I have a massive notebook and any little output means modifying a very large document.

Instead of removing outputs I went to

**Edit > Notebook Settings**

[image]

And select
**Omit code cell output when saving this notebook**

[image]

That reduces drastically the network traffic needed to keep the document Saved and the chances of it reaching 'Save failed'.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and eventually I found it's because I set up the hardware accelerator.
This would be fixed if reseting the 'Runtime/Change runtime type' to 'None'.